# Sum columns with similar names in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R with several columns called "SECOND1" , .... "SECOND54" and "SECONDother". I want to create a new column and add the sum of the values for each row across all columns that start with "SECOND" and are followed by a number in their column name. How would I do this please?

At the moment I am doing this manually for each column which makes me feel really stupid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `grep` -

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(SECOND1 = c(1, 2) , SECOND2 = c(1, NA) , SECOND54 = c(1, NA), SECONDother =  c(1, NA))
```

and then:

```
df$sum <- rowSums(df[,grep("^SECOND[0-9]", colnames(df))], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Result:

```
# SECOND1 SECOND2 SECOND54 SECONDother  sum
# 1       1       1        1            3
# 2       NA      NA       NA           2
```

`grep` accepts regular expressions. The `^` denotes it has to start with SECOND and the `[0-9]` denotes the next character after SECOND has  to be a number.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this doesn't work as the column I have that is called "Secondother" does not have numeric values. It has text which is why I need to ignore it. I need to specify that what comes after Second is a number. I also deleted that column for ease but it still doesn't work. I get the message 

Error in rowSums(Feb_data[grepl("^SECOND*", names(Feb_data))]) : 
  'x' must be numeric

Comment: Ah, just reread your question, missed that the first time sorry.

Comment: Actually it works if I rename that column so all good. Only issue is it seems to be introducing NAs!

Comment: Updated the answer so that it does what your question asked. And have added `na.rm=TRUE` to deal with those NAs.

Comment: Thanks this seems to add all the data I have for everyone not for every row (patient ID). The answer above worked though so I've managed to do it, thanks so much all for your help!!

Comment: No worries. I've updated  the code so that it does what you wanted, once again apologies for not reading your question properly (again!).

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr` you could do (Thx to @GuedesBF for teaching me to use `dplyr::pick` instead of using `across`.)

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

dat |>
  mutate(sum = rowSums(pick(matches("^SECOND\\d+$"))))
#>   id SECOND1 SECOND2 SECOND3 SECONDother sum
#> 1  1       1       4       7          10  12
#> 2  2       2       5       8          10  15
#> 3  3       3       6       9          10  18
```

Or using base R

```
dat$sum <- rowSums(dat[grepl("^SECOND\\d+$", names(dat))])

dat
#>   id SECOND1 SECOND2 SECOND3 SECONDother sum
#> 1  1       1       4       7          10  12
#> 2  2       2       5       8          10  15
#> 3  3       3       6       9          10  18
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  SECOND1 = 1:3,
  SECOND2 = 4:6,
  SECOND3 = 7:9,
  SECONDother = 10
)
```

Comment: We can also use `pick` instead of `across`, as suggested in the release of dplyr 1.1.0. `across` without a `.fns` argument works just fine, but this is the exact use case for the new `pick`. https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/02/dplyr-1-1-0-pick-reframe-arrange/

Comment: @GuedesBF Thx. Will have a look. Still struggling to keep up with all the changes in the latest release. (:

Comment: Ok, you are welcome. This release was awesome, some very nice improvements in several packages. New `tidyr::unnest_*` functions, the `.default` argument in `case_when`, the new `case_match`, `pick` are just a few of them.

Comment: @GuedesBF Yeah. `case_match` is great but still miss `case_regex`. Or have I missed that option. :D

Comment: That's awesome thank you so much. It works though it somehow incorporates NAs even though there is no NAs in any of the columns. All of them are either 0 or 1. Any idea where the NAs might be coming from or how to fix?

Comment: Can only guess why there are NAs and would suggest to check the data once more. But we could of course add `na.rm=TRUE`, i.e. try e.g. `mutate(sum = rowSums(pick(matches("^SECOND\\d+$")), na.rm = TRUE))` in the `dplyr` approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try `startsWith` or [`grepl` (as @stefan did)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75795482/12158757)

```
rowSums(df[startsWith(names(df), "SECOND")])
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
   mutate(Sum = pick(starts_with("SECOND")) %>% reduce(`+`))
```